# Print whitespace within jinja loop

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to print the list of hosts in an `ansible` task;

I want to have spaces among them, however the following loop does not achieve the purpose:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] -%} {{ host }}:6379 {%- endfor %}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're aiming to get them all on a single line and don't mind having a space at the start you could simply do:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] -%} {{ ' ' ~ host }}:6379 {%- endfor %}
```

You could also add a character to the end of each item (e.g space or something else), while skipping the last one. Note the space between the if and endif:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] -%}
{{ host }}:6379
{%- if not loop.last %} {% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for both options; used the second one, seems more elegant;

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the jinia loop, you could use ansibles join-filter, see in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8

in this case :

```
{{ groups["all"] | join(":6379 ") }}
```

Join is the opposite for split. split takes a string and a delimiter and then return a list. join takes a list and a string to concatenate all list-elements to one string.